# How to select (& copy) only a part (in the middle) of a linked text?

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

Example link:

> [The artist John Doe shows us his cat!](http://example.com/)

I want to copy the text "John Doe" only.

It should work while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> (according to [this](https://superuser.com/a/583801/151741) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/482537/151741) answer), but for me this would move the whole window instead. Am I doing something wrong? Has Ubuntu resp. Ubuntu’s Firefox a different key to allow this?

Comment: Have you tried this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-toggler/)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> works for me most of the times, although I'm not on Ubuntu, but on another Linux distro. WinKey is that key branded with the Redmond company logo.

Comment: This works for me. The "WinKey" is more commonly (in Ubuntu circles) called the Super key.

Comment: For me **Alt** + **AltGr** + **drag** works too.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> does not work under Linux, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> instead

Comment: Hm, does it work for you? When I place my cursor in the middle of the link while holding *Ctrl* and *Alt*, it creates a border around the whole question (probably focuses the parent block level HTML element).

Comment: Yes, get the same when trying links in the Q&A, but if I try it on links on the right, e.g. underneath Community Bulletin or Related, then it works for me.

Comment: Ah, right, for me too. Unfortunately, the link fires as soon as I release the mouse button. So I wouldn't be able to copy some text without opening the link, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable Alt click window drag as shown at: [How can I disable alt+click window dragging?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521423/how-can-i-disable-altclick-window-dragging)

Once that is done, it is possible to select with Alt + Click.

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10.