# How can I disable alt+click window dragging?

Tags: unity, 14.04, window

In Ubuntu 14.04, when you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click a window, you can drag it around.  As I understand, you used to be able to disable it through gconf, but Unity doesn't read settings from here any more (hence not being able to change where the window buttons are any more).

There's no setting for this by default, and I can't find anything in Unity Tweak Tool either.  Is there anyway to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click window movement in 14.04?

Comment: Close voters! This post has answers that are superior to the called duplicate. Merge candidate?  maybe. Close? never

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/428974/how-to-enable-dragging-windows-with-alt-click-in-gnome-3-gnome-shell

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In 14.04 (or 14.10, 15.04, 15.10, 16.04), to set the default key / value:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier  '"<Alt>"'
```

You can give it a (limited number of) other value(s), but **DON'T** set it to `none` like you could in the past. **Nor should you set it to an empty string**,  Doing either will give you some trouble getting control over your mouse back, as I found out...

The practical value of this information is quite limited, since not many alternative keys are accepted. I found only `Shift` and `Super` to be working, which I doubt will give you the solution you'd like to have.

Of course you can use `dconf-editor` as well:

```
org>gnome>desktop>wm>preferences
```

[image]

Comment: kcpr's solution lets you set it to something like `<Shift><Control><Alt><Super>Button20` pretty easily. Will be hard to accidentally trigger that.

Comment: FYI, this still works in 16.04.

Comment: @JohnPBloch ah, great, good to hear. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: This also works on 17.10.

Comment: works perfectly ;) P.S **DO NOT TRY to set it to the empty string**. I tried :) Mouse will just always move windows. Can't select anything. Clicked on some window and you are dragging it around instead of selecting something. You will have to undo this w/o mouse.

Comment: You can install dconf-editor with `sudo apt install dconf-tools`.

Answer (score 30):

Today I've learned that pressing key

> **Super**

together with

> **Alt + Click**

circumvents (deactivates) the dragging behavior. Solved my issues at least, as the application (Inkscape) I wanted to use **Alt+Click** with, seems to simply ignore the additional key (**Super**) been pressed.

sf. https://askubuntu.com/a/445254/618422

#edit

By the way, it's also documented officially at:

<s>https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/basic/tutorial-basic.en.html#Selecting_under_and_dragging_selected</s>

https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/basic/tutorial-basic.html

Comment: THIS is by far the awesomest thing I've seen today! Thanks - this is why I was trying to disable the ALT -drag in the first place! Thanks buddy!

Comment: I needed this for notepad++ square selection/column mode editing inside a windows vm. Very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Best solution which doesn't need us to over-write the system settings

Comment: 2020 Best answer

Comment: Great! Works on Cinnamon. Make sure to hold Alt before Super though. I used this in Unity to enable rotating view around selection. By the way, link is dead, I found the page at https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/basic/tutorial-basic.html (but it just recommended to disable window dragging or remap it to Super/Meta as in other answers).

Comment: This also worked for me in Bitwig!

Answer (score 16):

You can also do this through Compiz Settings Manager.
Just install it with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.
The addon is called 'Move' and is located in section called 'Window Management' I believe.
You can go straight to its settings with `ccsm -p move`.

I really recommend this application. It gives access to massive amount of system customization options.

Comment: Indeed, super easy this way.

Comment: You will also need to do `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins` to get the Window Management option

Comment: How to save changes in this application? Unchecking option for Alt-move does nothing and does return on next run

Comment: @Dims, I believe it should be saved automatically. Maybe just try changing the modifier from `alt` to something else (`super` is my personal favorite).

Comment: I'm using deepin, both ways doesn't work with me

Answer (score 9):

You can us **CompizConfig Settings Manager** (**CCSM**).  This tool is essential if you want to tweak Linux for better efficiency, because it makes it easy to configure the desktop environment to be much more efficient then out-of-the-box Ubuntu.  I used to use things like *dconf-editor*, and *Ubuntu Tweak*, but for tweaking anything related to desktop behavior, I have found **CCSM** to be much more powerful and easy to use.

1. Install **CompizConfig Settings Manager** by typing this in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-extra
   ```
2. Open CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager), go to the **Window Management** section, and find the **Move Windows** icon.
3. Make sure **Move Window** is enabled, and then Click it's button.

[image]

4. Click the button to the right of the **Initiate Move Window** with the mouse icon next to it.

[image]

4. In the **Edit Initiate Window Move** window, and then make sure to un-check the **Enabled** check-box.  That will disable it.  You can also easily set the Window Move to a different mouse/keyboard/screen-edge combination, if you would like, although binding it to a screen edge wouldn't work.  This is where this tool, **CCSM**, outdoes *dconf-editor* and *Ubuntu Tweak*.

[image]

Comment: Disabling the shortcut didn't work for me in Ubuntu 16.04, instead I had to change the default shortcut.

Comment: You will also need to do sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins to get the Window Management option

Comment: I never install compiz-plugins, because I assumed compiz-plugins was installed by default, and I still have the Windows Management feature.  I do, however, install compiz-plugins-extra on all my Linux installations, so maybe that's where I get the Windows Management plugin.  So I added both of them to the command line above.

Comment: Changing the shortcut worked for 18.04

Answer (score 5):

You can also use GNOME Tweak Tool (`gnome-tweak-tool`).

In 'Windows' section, change the 'Window Action Key' setting.

This tool is obviously for the GNOME Shell tweaking, but some properties are respected by Unity as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using KDE Plasma then you can use System Settings.

1. Search for System Settings in the Application Launcher or run systemsettings
2. Click Window Management under the Workspace section
3. On the left select Window Behavior and go to the third tab labeled Window Actions.
4. The second section is labeled Inner Window, Titlebar & Frame. You can change any of these drop-down menus to 'Nothing' to disable their action.

[image: Window Actions Menu]

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use `dconf-editor` but the setting didn't work. A little obvious, but if you are using **cinnamon** instead of GNOME then you should edit:

```
org > cinnamon > desktop > wm > preferences
```

Comment: Yep, using Ubuntu 18.04 I forgot about that - this works for all with dconf-editor - you just need to use the right "org" - for cinnamon or **any other** => `org > ` **`cinnamon`** `> desktop > wm > preferences > mouse-button-modifier` ; for gnome => `org > gnome > desktop > wm > preferences > mouse-button-modifier` etc ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're on KDE (Kubuntu), you go to:

```
Settings → Window Management → Window Behaviour → Window Actions → *
```

Then Change the Modifier Key to Meta or change the Left click to something else.