# Disabling alt-click on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, 17.04

I'm using `Pycharm` to write some code, I have A LOT of small functions that need to be indented into a class and not enough patience to do it all one by one. In `Pycharm` you can use `alt-click` to add [multiple carets](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/multicursor.html). However in Ubuntu `alt-click` will drag the window. How can I disable `alt-click` on Ubuntu as a system configuration, in order to use it for multiple carets?

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521423/how-can-i-disable-altclick-window-dragging/521444#521444) answer using `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier  '"<Alt>"'` but it doesn't seem to do anything, and the `alt-drag/click` still pulls the window with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager) I was able to change the settings of the `alt-click` to `cntrl-alt-click`

To do so:

- `sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- CCSM > Window Management > Initiate Window Move