# How to Crop in OBS?

Tags: obs-studio

I have [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) installed via command line and am trying to crop a certain regions of my screen.

Usually this is accomplished via alt + tugging one of the red handle bars, but this doesn't work for some reason.

Instead, it wants to move the entire window.

I'm following the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZx9y6xcPXI tutorial.

How can I crop the screen in the same way that he does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and other desktops, the main window manager already uses the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>, so it captures that shortcut rather than OBS.

### Solution 1 - Permanent - Modify the existing handler to allow OBS to receive the Alt-Click

You need to disable this behavior or change the modifier key to a different one. For Ubuntu, you may need to install `dconf-editor` as noted in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521423/how-can-i-disable-altclick-window-dragging). For Linux Mint, this is a built-in option within the Windows preference panel.

### Solution 2 - Temporary - Press the Windows key along with Alt

Alternatively, you can make OBS work without changing anything at all. Simply press  <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to crop the scene sources. That stops the desktop manager from performing its window drag shortcut, and OBS accepts or ignores the extra Windows keypress and executes its crop as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I see this was a year ago, so don't know if you are still interested. I had the same problem and have found a partial answer. For Window Capture items if you right click on the item and choose properties, you can manually crop by entering the numbers in the dialog box. It is a bit laborious, but does work